# Div not expanding with picture

Tags: html

I have a div and when i put a picture inside that dive and only set the width of the picture so it can have its proper proportions the div does not expand to the size of the div its in?

Please could you help?

(If you run the code below I want the pink div to expand when I add anything into it)

Thanks a lot!

html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="gigantic">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="twitterPP">
                <img src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2015016150/petecashmoreavatar_normal.png">
            </div>
            <div class="mainMedia">
                <img src="http://rack.1.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDEzLzAzLzA4LzY1L2F0dC4yZjU4Mi5qcGcKcAl0aHVtYgk5NTB4NTM0IwplCWpwZw/91fe06f6/108/att.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.gigantic
{
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #0f0;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.main 
{
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #f0f;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.twiterpp
{
    width: 60px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.twitterpp img
{
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    position: relative;
}

.mainMedia
{
    float: right;
    width: 700px;
}

.mainMedia img
{
    width: 700px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use height:auto; to set the height of the div automatically when the image changes. The same for width as well if you want to set the width automatically.

Also you typed .twitterpp when it should be .twitterPP. Avoid using caps for classes and ids.

Comment: Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/UcKdn/ You will know what to do. I changed the size of the main div to allow my picture to fit inside. I imagine your picture won't be that huge.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting like this -

HTML

```
<div class="img-box"></div>
```

Css -

```
.img-box {
background-image: url(images/yourimg.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
}
```

Then set width to match your own preference and padding to control image placement